# Hide an html element when it loses focus using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I've made a datepicker for a custom form and I want to hide it when the input lost the focus and the next focused element is not the datepicker (when you focus another input for example). The problem is that the `blur` event on the input happens before `focus` on the datepicker. This is the regular behaviour of the JS events. But I want to close the datepicker only if the input loses the focus and the datepicker is not focused then. Is there any way to achieve this without blocking the user interface using `setTimeout()` or something similar?

I'm not asking for a code solution, just the process to follow or any alternative. Thanks.

This is a screenshot of the datepicker and the input:

[image]

And this is the html code just to give an idea on what's going on (It has Angular bindings and template references mixed):

```
<div class="col-lg-2 form-group">
    <label for="date">Fecha</label>
    <input type="text"
           class="form-control datepicker-input"
           id="date"
           placeholder="Fecha"
           readonly="true"
           formControlName="date"
           #datepickerInput>
    <app-datepicker [datepickerInput]="datepickerInput"
                    (pickDate)="onPickDate($event)"></app-datepicker>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would treat the date picker as a popup:

- Add a  full screen transparent overlay behind the calendar
- When the user clicks that overlay (not on the calendar itself that is), close the calendar
- While the calendar is open, respond to specific key events like `[Esc]` to close the calendar

Hope that helps

Comment: Hi! Yes, in the first approach I do it like that. But when the user press the tab key and the focus goes to the next input for example the calendar stills open and I want to close it.

Comment: In that case the `blur` event should work. The whole point is for you to take ownership of the open close state of the datepicker. There is no easy built in solution in the DOM itself I am afraid.

Comment: The problem is that when you click the datepicker to pick a date after clicking the input to open it, the input blurs and then the datepickers gets closed...

Comment: Then you can listen to the tab key event and close it

Comment: Yes, but if you click another input instead of using the tab key it won’t work

Comment: It will work because they will have to click the transparent overlay. Anyways there are plenty of datepickers out there, why don't you look at how they solved that problem or even better reuse one of those ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not real sure to understand your need... Since what you wish to do sounds like the normal behavior of bootstrap's datepicker. But you mentioned a *custom form*... So I don't know.

Now the issue is about a delay between `blur` the input and `focus` the datepicker dropdown.

Here, I would talk about `mouseup` on the dropdown, since `focus` is more about inputs than divs. And it doesn't work using `click`, since that event is used by datepicker and there must be a return false somewhere because it just doesn't fire on a datepicker dropdown. Anyway... Your `setTimeout` idea is something simple to achieve.

The trick:

1. Set a timeout on input `blur` to hide the dropdown.
2. On `mouseup` on the dropdown, clear that timeout.

Normally, if the user is focussing the input and clicks on the opened dropdown, the delay in between is around 100ms. Using that value results in fail once on 3~4 times. So let's use 150ms.

Here is the code:

```js
$("#date").datepicker();

var dp_timeout;
$(".datepicker-input").on("blur",function(){
  dp_timeout = setTimeout(function(){
    $(".datepicker").hide();
    console.log("Timeout executed");
  },150);
});

$(document).on("mouseup",".datepicker-dropdown",function(){
  clearTimeout(dp_timeout);
  console.log("Timeout canceled");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="col-lg-2 form-group">
  <label for="date">Fecha</label>
  <input type="text"
         class="form-control datepicker-input"
         id="date"
         placeholder="Fecha"
         readonly="true"
         formControlName="date"
         #datepickerInput>
  <app-datepicker [datepickerInput]="datepickerInput"
                  (pickDate)="onPickDate($event)"></app-datepicker>
</div>
```